# How to obtain the contact Uri directly with contact creation

Tags: android, uri, lookup, contacts

my app creates new contacts with ContentProviderOperation. The problem is, I need a reference to the new contact because I need some information of it to display it in a listview and go with intent into the contact app to the contact.

The best thing would be the ID, but I´ve read that it might change during operations on the database, which won´t be helpful to me.

Now I thought, the Uri might be the best thing, because I could later retrieve the contactID or lookup key.

How do I get the Uri directly after calling applyBatch() ?

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2011/03/android-contacts-%E2%80%93-custom-contact-column-to-get-the-lookupkey/#.Ujw_x9K9VSJ) is a solution, but not really a good one.

He is putting a randomly generated token into each contact, then he makes a new query with it.

I want neither put some extra data into the contacts, nor starting a second query. But if there is no other possibility I´ll do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

simply call

```
 private String retrieveContactId(String phoneNo) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNo));
            String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
            String selection = null;
            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
            ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            String contactId = null;
            if (cr != null) {
                Cursor resultCur = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                if (resultCur != null) {
                    while (resultCur.moveToNext()) {
                        contactId = resultCur.getString(resultCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
                        Log.e("Info Incoming", "Contact Id : " + contactId);
                        return contactId;
                    }
                    resultCur.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception sfg) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error in loadContactRecord : " + sfg.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and for the uri

```
 Uri contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(
                Integer.valueOf(rawContactId), clookup);
```

Comment: that means, I should simply query the contact by it´s unique phone number, right? but what, if some contacts do not have any number?

Comment: you can query the RAW contacts table with whatever field that you have and then get the contact id for that RAW contact row

Comment: okay, then i might need to query for each detail until I find a match